# newid() inside sql server function

Tags: sql-server, function, newid

I have to insert a fake column at the result of a query, which is the return value of a table-value function. This column data type must be unique-identifier. The best way (I think...) is to use `newid()` function. The problem is, I can't use `newid()` inside this type of function:

> Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'newid()' within a function.

Comment: Functions are not allowed to contain non-deterministic operators. Can you post your function definition?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Here's a clever solution:

```
    create view getNewID as select newid() as new_id
    
    create function myfunction ()
    returns uniqueidentifier
    as begin
       return (select new_id from getNewID)
    end
```

That I can't take credit for. I found it [here](http://omnibuzz-sql.blogspot.com/2006/07/accessing-non-deterministic-functions.html)

Answer (score 21):

You can pass NEWID() as a parameter to your function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SOMEIDFUNCTION
(
    @NEWID1 as varchar(36), @NEWID2 as varchar(36)
)
RETURNS varchar(18)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do something --
    DECLARE @SFID varchar(18)
    SELECT @SFID = 'DYN0000000' + LOWER(LEFT(@NEWID1,4)) + LEFT(@NEWID2,4) 
    RETURN @SFID
END
GO
```

Call the function like this;

```
SELECT dbo.SOMEIDFUNCTION(NewID(),NewID())
```

Answer (score 5):

use it as a default instead

```
create table test(id uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),id2 int)

insert test(id2) values(1)

select * from test
```

NB I used newsequentialid() instead of newid() since newid() will cause pagesplits since it is not sequential, see here: [Some Simple Code To Show The Difference Between Newid And Newsequentialid](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2009/02/05/11743.aspx)

Comment: yes, unfortunately some people make it a PK without realizing it is clustered....believe me I have seen many such instances

Comment: Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newsequentialid' within a function.

Answer (score -7):

You could use ROW_NUMBER function:

SELECT 
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recordID) ) as RowNumber , 
        recordID, 
        fieldBla1  
FROM tableName

Find more information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx