# sql insert into table which uses newid in user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, newid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [newid() inside sql server function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function)

I have to return a value  based on parameter from the function which looks into the table
and when it's null insert into this table new record.
Unfortunately I'm getting this funny error:
 invalid use of side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function

Is there a work around providing I cannot change the target table?
Working on SQL Server 2008
thanks!

Comment: You cannot use non-deterministic functions like `newid()` in a user defined function. There are suggestions in this [_other question_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function) on how to work around that restriction.

Comment: I don't see then possible solution or workaround to that problem since I cannot change the target table which uses newid in one the columns in connection with uniqueidentifier. I read I cannot call a proc from the function either... :(