# Can I create a synonym for t-sql built in function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a function dbo.GENERATE_UUID does exactly what it says.
I want to maintain the name for compatiblity, but would rather use the built in [NEWID().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)
However, I cannot do this

```
alter function dbo.GENERATE_UUID ()
returns uniqueidentifier
as begin
   return (SELECT NEWID())
end
```

because "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function."

So I would like to instead

```
drop function dbo.GENERATE_UUID
```

and

```
create synonym dbo.GENERATE_UUID for NEWID
```

but when I

```
select dbo.GENERATE_UUID()
```

I get, "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GENERATE_UUID", or the name is ambiguous."

I also tried variations on

```
create synonym dbo.GENERATE_UUID for master.sys.NEWID
```

Is there anyway to create a SYNONYM for this sort of TSQL built in function? Am interested in any version of SQL Server post 2k5.

Comment: Check [NewID in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function) and [Accessing non-deterministic functions in UDF](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/07/accessing-non-deterministic-functions.html)

Comment: @amit_g: I saw that. In fact that's basically what I want to replace. We don't actually call them within a function so I could just use NEWID(). However existing code use the custom wrapper AND the same custom wrapper is provided in our Oracle version. A synonym, if possible, would provide a clean transition.

Comment: Not sure if this helps (but I found it interesting):  executing `SELECT dbo.GENERATE_UUID()` generates the same error, whether you create the synonym or not.

Comment: I was thinking about a view that selects NEWID() and having your `GENERATE_UUID` udf select the first row from the view to get around the "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function." issue...[But someone beat me to it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function)

Comment: Yes, we can get around the side affects that way. But in my usage I am not concerned about the side affecting. Specifically I work with an application that uses both Oracle and SQL Server and being able to synonym the function would allow me to keep a little more code the same between the two platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your version of SQL server it looks like yes.  SQL Scalar function under remarks.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: User defined SQL Scalar function certainly, but I'm asking about a synonym for a built in function.