# Return a random row number using a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, sql-function

I'm trying to write a function that selects a set of rows from a table and returns one of these randomly. The first steps of the function create and fill a local table variable holding the suitable row IDs. The table is defined as such:

```
DECLARE @SuitableID TABLE (
  Id INT
)
```

This table can hold any number of IDs. The function needs to return one of these randomly, but I can't find out how to do it. I've tried the following:

```
DECLARE @ReturnedID INT
SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnedID = Id
FROM @SuitableID
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Which returns an error:

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'newid' within a function.
```

TAMPLESAMPLE also doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT @ReturnedID = Id
FROM @SuitableID
TABLESAMPLE (1 ROWS)
```

I think this syntax is correct, but my database disagrees.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLESAMPLE'.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I perform the operation I want?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this and similar cases, I usually have a special view in the database:

```
create view [dbo].[sys_ViewNDF]
as
select rand() as [Rnd], getdate() as [Now], getutcdate() as [UTCNow], newid() as [GUID];
```

You can then join it with your table inside your UDF, like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @ReturnedID = s.Id
FROM @SuitableID s
  cross join dbo.sys_ViewNDF v
ORDER BY v.GUID;
```

Comment: Thanks to the comment by Nenad, I'd already been put on this track. This is indeed a working solution.

Comment: Interesting.  I have similar views but never considered combining them  +1

Answer (score 0):

Can this be usefull to you? At least it works :)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.GetNewID
AS
SELECT NewId() AS [NewID]
GO


CREATE FUNCTION GetRandomID()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SuitableID TABLE (
Id INT
)

insert into @SuitableID (ID)
values(1),(2),(3)
RETURN (
 SELECT TOP 1 ID
 FROM @SuitableID
 ORDER BY (SELECT [NewId] FROM GetNewID)
)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.GetRandomID()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS bigint)
```

This selects a random number so i dont know if you can incorporate this in

Comment: This returns the same error as using `NEWID()`: Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'Crypt_Gen_Random' within a function.

Comment: create it as a function and then call it