# Prevent Grouping rows by NULL value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[According to this article:](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4082/some-tricky-situations-when-working-with-sql-server-nulls/)

> When grouping with a column in a GROUP BY statement that contains NULLs, they will be put into **one** group in your result set:

However, what I want is to prevent grouping rows by NULL value.

The following code gives me one row:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTable') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #TestTable
GO 

CREATE TABLE #TestTable ( ID INT, Value INT )

INSERT INTO #TestTable(ID, Value) VALUES 
(NULL, 70),
(NULL, 70)


SELECT 
  ID
, Value
FROM #TestTable 
GROUP BY ID, Value
```

The output is:

```
ID     Value
NULL    70
```

However, I would like to have two rows. My desired result looks like this:

```
NULL    70
NULL    70
```

Is it possible to have two rows with `GROUP BY`?

**UPDATE:**

What I need is to count those rows:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(1) AS rows
FROM (SELECT 1 AS foo
    FROM #TestTable 
    GROUP BY ID, Value
)q
```

OUTPUT: 1

But, actually, there are two rows.  I need output to have 2.

Comment: It is if you remove the group by...

Comment: You will need to provide better examples. Maybe with different values for `Value` and/or with some non-null values for `ID`- I for one have no idea what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Is it possible to have with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my table has above columns such as `ID` and `Value` and I am trying to GROUP BY these rows. My goal is to show these rows as different

Comment: But those rows are **not** different. And again: what do you want as the result if you have more (different) values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please, see my updated question

Comment: Do you need to count distinct values where `id` is null? because that can be done easily: `select count(distinct value) from #TestTable where id is null;`

Comment: @ZoharPeled no, my goal is to treat NULL's as non equal values  to count of rows.

Comment: Well, I've shown you a way to do that in my answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I really cannot understand this behavior, but why `s
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL=NULL THEN 1
ELSE 2 END` is `2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a way to make `NULL` values in `Id` unique. Using the following code will make the values unique, but continue to group the non-NULL value by virtue of the default value for a `case` expression being `NULL`:

```
group by Id, case when Id is NULL then NewId() end, Value
```

Comment: Searching for `t sql udf newid` with <my favorite search engine> turns up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/775573/92546).

Comment: Yeah, that's better and shorter than my answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want this behavior because you do want to group by the values of the nullable column (`Id` in your example), you can add a row_number when the `id` column is null using a common table expression to create an artificial difference between duplicate groups - like this:

```
-- Adding some more rows to the table
INSERT INTO #TestTable(ID, Value) VALUES 
(NULL, 70),
(NULL, 70),
(1, 70),
(1, 70),
(2, 70);
```

The query, with the cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, Value, IIF(Id IS NULL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id), NULL) As Surrogate
    FROM #TestTable 
)
SELECT 
  ID
, Value
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID, Surrogate, Value
```

Results:

```
ID      Value
NULL    70
NULL    70
1       70
2       70
```